# Container of Type Superclass

Tags: java, oop

If I have a class A which is super class of classes B and C and I have

```
A as[] = new A[1];
```

then how much space will as occupy the size of A, B or C?

Comment: A reference will not occupy much space its like pointer or reference to other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `as` is an array of length 1.  In Java, arrays containing objects actually contain *references* to objects, and a reference takes either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the hardware architecture.

You haven't allocated any objects of type `A`, or any of its subtypes, so the total memory used is the memory occupied by a single reference (4 or 8 bytes).

If you were to do

```
as[0] = new A();
```

then you would additionally have however much memory `A` takes up, which depends on what `A` contains.  If you did

```
as[0] = new B();
```

the memory usage would be whatever `B` takes up, which depends on `B`'s members but would be ≥ `A`'s memory requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> then how much space will as occupy the size of A, B or C?

That doesn't make sense.

`as` is an array of `A` type references. It should be `[space a reference would take] X 1`, because your array size is 1.